# MySQL table has data but not showing in select query

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

I have a scenario something like this :

```
mysql> SELECT table_name AS "Tables",  round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB"   , TABLE_ROWS , TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_CATALOG FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = "db_name" ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
+------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| Tables                 | Size in MB | TABLE_ROWS | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_CATALOG |
+------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| break_minute_tvr_fixed |   40815.00 |  121919728 | db_name      | def           |
| break_minute_tvr       |   38915.00 |  171440310 | db_name      | def           |
| break_tvr              |   12117.86 |   42930205 | db_name      | def           |
| program_tvr            |   10707.00 |   53913063 | db_name      | def           |
| day_parts              |   10362.00 |   65395774 | db_name      | def           |
| ad_details             |   10083.00 |   27879879 | db_name      | def           |
| panel_weight_map       |     449.55 |    7429541 | db_name      | def           |
| universe               |      92.22 |     824228 | db_name      | def           |
| users                  |       0.05 |          2 | db_name      | def           |
| PanelListPerMinute     |       0.02 |         10 | db_name      | def           |
+------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> use db_name;
Database changed
mysql> select * from break_minute_tvr;
Empty set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW TABLES FROM db_name where Tables_in_db_name LIKE 'break_minute_tvr';
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_db_name    |
+----------------------+
| break_minute_tvr     |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

I had a original table say break_minute_tvr_org and I have renamed it to break_minute_tvr. But after that I am facing this issue. Also my break_minute_tvr_org is no more in my schema.

I have my MySQL hosted in Amazon rds. SO I cannot login into the machine.

Comment: Did you see the table in "SHOW TABLES FROM db_name WHERE Tables_in_db_name LIKE 'break_minute_tvr'"?

Comment: I have added the above query result in the question only.

Comment: Can you run "Analyze" on the database? That should bring the table rows field into sync.

Comment: break_minute_tvr_fixed has the same problem ?

Comment: Yes beak_minute_tvr_fixed has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run EXPLAIN on query, are you sure that the table not empty ? 
try to make table copy.(Data + Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE break_minute_tvr_test LIKE db_name.break_minute_tvr; 
INSERT break_minute_tvr_test SELECT * FROM db_name.break_minute_tvr;
```